# Magento 2 Open Source End of Life Timeline

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, patches

Does anybody have the timeframe for end of life support for Magento 2 Open Source? All I've been able to find from an official source is this (https://magento.com/legal/terms/enterprise-agreement#support), which is for Enterprise/Commerce editions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can find the official pdf here](https://magento.com/sites/default/files/magento-open-source-software-maintenance-policy.pdf)

[image]